# read and change xml attribute with php

Tags: php, xml

this is part of my file xml:

```html
<office:body>
  <office:text>
    <text:sequence-decls>
      <text:sequence-decl text:name="Illustration" text:display-outline-level="0"/>
      <text:sequence-decl text:name="Table" text:display-outline-level="0"/>
      <text:sequence-decl text:name="Text" text:display-outline-level="0"/>
      <text:sequence-decl text:name="Drawing" text:display-outline-level="0"/>
    </text:sequence-decls>
    <text:p text:style-name="P2">pippo</text:p>
  </office:text>
</office:body>
```

I want to read the "text:style-name" for "pippo"  (P2 in the example..) and change it in P1

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean "change it _to_ P1"?  If so, would `str_replace` work?

Comment: Look into PHP's [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and make some attempts.

Comment: @Bing I only know "pippo" and first, I have to read "text:style-name" value, and leater change it with other value (P1 for example)

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is missing the namespace definitions (The xmlns:* attributes). They are really important. I use dummy namespace URIs in the answer, but you will have to replace that with the real URIs.

In DOM you can use Xpath Xpath expression to fetch specific nodes and anything is a node - the elements, attributes, text content...

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<office:body xmlns:office="urn:office" xmlns:text="urn:text">
  <office:text>
    <text:sequence-decls>
      <text:sequence-decl text:name="Illustration" text:display-outline-level="0"/>
      <text:sequence-decl text:name="Table" text:display-outline-level="0"/>
      <text:sequence-decl text:name="Text" text:display-outline-level="0"/>
      <text:sequence-decl text:name="Drawing" text:display-outline-level="0"/>
    </text:sequence-decls>
    <text:p text:style-name="P2">pippo</text:p>
  </office:text>
</office:body>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);

// create an Xpath instance and register the namespace
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('t', 'urn:text');

// fetch the "style" attribute of the "p" node with the text "pippo"
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//t:p[text() = "pippo"]/@t:style-name') as $styleName) {
  // attribute nodes have a value property that you can read and write
  var_dump($styleName->value);
  $styleName->value = 'P1';
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
string(2) "P2"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<office:body xmlns:office="urn:office" xmlns:text="urn:text">
  <office:text>
    <text:sequence-decls/>
    <text:p text:style-name="P1">pippo</text:p>
  </office:text>
</office:body>
```

Comment: ok, XML is missing the namespace definitions (The xmlns:* attributes), but the xml I posted, is a part of content.xml, of a file .odt, saved by LibreOffice !